# How to detect pressing dash key in C# using Hotkeys

Tags: c#, keyboard, hotkeys

I want to detect when the user type Dash regardless of his keyboard layout.
I'm using the code [suggested by Przemysław Kalita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291854/5239003)

```
ghk = new KeyHandler(Keys.PrintScreen, this); // I want to detect the dash press event 
                                             // instead of the PrintScreen keypress  
ghk.Register();
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated?

Comment: Your issue may be that you're using "subtract" instead of the "dash", I believe they are two separate key presses.
Try using a key of Code 189 in place of your Keys.PrintScreen: ghk = new KeyHandler(Keys.PrintScreen, this);

Comment: Do you mean doing this     ghk = new KeyHandler((Keys)189, this); ?