# Find which key a user is pressing without form focus

Tags: c#, keyboard, event-handling, key

I am currently making lighting profile for a G910 RGB Orion Spectrum keyboard using the Logitech SDK. I am trying to implement a ripple effect. The SDK provides adequate functionality to do the ripple itself, but I am currently struggling with **how I can figure out which key the user has pressed.**

I need to be able to find out which key the user pressed **without the form** (hopefully being used to start the effect) **being focused**.

I know there are answers here: [How do I detect keyPress while not focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused) and here [Capture a keyboard keypress in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background) but these questions link to tracking one particular key, and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution for tracking **any** key.

Documentation for the logitech SDK can be downloaded here if required: http://gaming.logitech.com/en-gb/developers (then go to LED Illumination SDK)

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, please make me aware of any glaring pieces of information I may have missed.