# Get KeyDown and KeyUp info on global hotkeys c#

Tags: c#, keyevent, global-hotkey

I registered global hotkeys as described here in c# [How do I detect keyPress while not focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused)

but it just detects if the button is pressed, but I need to know when the key is pressed down and when it is released again.

Comment: check this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/

Comment: That's not possible, the OS only turns the WM_KEYDOWN notification into a corresponding WM_HOTKEY notification.  Nor would that be very practical since you typically activate another window.  Hmm.  You need a hook that sees everything, takes SetWindowsHookEx to set a low-level keyboard hook.  Lots and lots of implementations in C#.

Comment: In the question **YOU** linked, follow the Accepted Answer and use a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL.

Comment: you should listen to KeyUp event as well.