# How to make winform active even when minimized?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am developing an application integrated to Digital Persona fingerprint reader. and im having a problem with its event listeners. The event listeners only works when the winform is focused. I want the event listeners (the capture event listener of the said device) to work even when the application is minimized or not focused. The only solution im thinking right now is to make the winform stay active even when minimized to make the event listeners work. Do anyone knows how to do this?

below is the code of dpfp event listeners

```
public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample)
{


}

public void OnFingerGone(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
{

}

public void OnFingerTouch(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
{

}

public void OnReaderConnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
{

}

public void OnReaderDisconnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the event listener's code you are using ?

Comment: Hi @KobyDouek i edited the question and included the code

Comment: I know, if you read the following question at first, it may not seem it would fit your problem, but please bear with it and read it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused    
Maybe you need a hook for your events like there.