# Wait for user KeyPress WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi my problem seems quite simple but I couldn't solve it alone.

I have a WinForms application and it has a button. When I press it some code runs and I want to have a loop inside it that breaks whenever any key is pressed.

I of course can't use Console.ReadKey() because it's a winforms and I don't want to have to click with the mouse on a button, also I don't want to use another EventArg.

Is there any way to detect a keystroke in a winforms application with a loop.

Here's the idea :

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
        while (Key is not pressed)
            { 
                try to detect key pressing
            }
        // Other stuff
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on what is going on with "some code runs". Is the form still receiving updates and the code running asynchronously?

Comment: You're better off having separate button and keyboard handlers and introduce a _flag_

Comment: You can't wait, that will hang the UI.  Simply set a bool variable to *true* in the Click event handler.  Then in the KeyPress event handler you can check the variable and do the //otherstuff.  Do think a bit how it needs to be reset back to *false*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect a key press while the form is focus or not you can use the anwser of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291854/10015658

So your code would like:

**Create new class "KeyHandler"**:

```
public class KeyHandler
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private int key;
    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private int id;

    public KeyHandler(Keys key, Form form)
    {
        this.key = (int)key;
        this.hWnd = form.Handle;
        id = this.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
    }

    public bool Register()
    {
        return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, 0, key);
    }

    public bool Unregiser()
    {
        return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
    }
}
```

**Your main From class:** (assume that your form class name is Form1)

```
private KeyHandler ghk;
bool isButtonClicked = false;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Keys.A is the key you want to subscribe
    ghk = new KeyHandler(Keys.A, this);
    ghk.Register();
}

private void HandleHotkey()
{
     // Key 'A' pressed

     if(isButtonClicked)
     {
         // Put the boolean to false to avoid spamming the function with multiple press
         isButtonClicked = false;

         // Other Stuff
     }
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff

    isButtonClicked = true;
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    //0x0312 is the windows message id for hotkey
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        HandleHotkey();
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**Do Not forget usings**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can acheive what you want.

A simple way is to set Form's KeyPreview to true and handle keypress event on form level. Note that you need to allow a break in your loop (Thread.Sleep() or Task.Delay()).

For advanced hook up to windows message, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to add an event handler for `KeyDown` once the button is clicked, let it wait for the key input, then trigger the second action and remove the event handler.

It would look something like this:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
    KeyEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = delegate (object s, KeyEventArgs ev)
    {
        if (ev.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            btn.KeyDown -= handler;
            // Do other stuff
        }
    };
    btn.KeyDown += handler;
}
```

Of course, you'd need to replace `Keys.A` with the actual key you want to "listen" for.