# Windows Forms Detecting Key Presses When Not Tabbed In

Tags: c#, windows

So i'm attempting to make an auto clicker for something, with a gui, im using .net framework for a windows forms project. How ever i'm not sure how to set up a hot key for when the process isn't tabbed in.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
        {
            // Code
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

is what i'm using, it correctly detects the key press when the gui is  tabbed in how ever when it's tabbed out it doesn't work.

With windows forms how do you detect key presses when the app isn't tabbed in

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused ?

Comment: I think by "tabbed in" you mean "has the focus" ?

Comment: Also, google for `c# keylogger` - various instructions such as https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/ abound

Comment: You need Win32 API call for it e.g. `RegisterHotKey` from `user32.dll`. I have a code example but for WPF. :( The question is very popular. Try looking for "Register Hotkey", "Global hotkey".

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge there are only dirty solutions in C# for creating a hotkey:
Recently I used [this](https://github.com/mrousavy/Hotkeys) library for setting a global hotkey.

I hope I could manage to help you.