# WinForms Global Hotkey Typing Interference

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-hook, registerhotkey

I am trying to get this keyboard hook to echo registered keys to a Label when pressed. My goal is to do this while the Window is out of focus.

> This program is only looking for the keys*: `w, a, s, d`

---

The issue I'm running into is that I can't type the letters `w, a, s, d` in any other programs (example: notepad) while this program is running.

---

Here is my Form class:

*Form1.cs*:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private KeyHandler _keyHandler;
    private List<Keys> keys = new List<Keys>() { Keys.W, Keys.A, Keys.S, Keys.D };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var key in keys) (_keyHandler = new KeyHandler(key, this)).Register();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }
    
    // Key Logger =======================
    private void HandleHotkey(int keyPress)
    {
        if (keyPress == 5701632)
            label1.Text = "W pressed";
        else if (keyPress == 4259840)
            label1.Text = "A pressed";
        else if (keyPress == 5439488)
            label1.Text = "S pressed";
        else if (keyPress == 4456448)
            label1.Text = "D pressed";
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
            HandleHotkey(m.LParam.ToInt32());
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

and the class it's using to register keys:

*KeyHandler.cs*:

```
public static class Constants
{
    //windows message id for hotkey
    public const int WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID = 0x0312;
}

public class KeyHandler
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private int key;
    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private int id;

    public KeyHandler(Keys key, Form form)
    {
        this.key = (int)key;
        this.hWnd = form.Handle;
        id = this.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
    }

    public bool Register()
    {
        return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, 0, key);
    }

    public bool Unregiser()
    {
        return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
    }
}
```

---

**I'll take all suggestions/answers. Thank you!**

---

### Update 1

I was able to use what [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) suggested, GetAsyncKeyState(). While this does not interfere with typing in other windows, it does not update my application window until it is back in focus.

*Form1.cs*

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HandleHotkey(Keys key)
        {
            label1.Text = key.ToString() + " done";
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            KeyState keyState = new KeyState();
            if (keyState.GetKeyState(Keys.W) == 1) HandleHotkey(Keys.W);

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

*KeyState.cs*

```cs
    public class KeyState
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

        public int GetKeyState(Keys key)
        {
            return GetAsyncKeyState(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Issue #2 has been solved by using `m.LParam` values in a `switch` method

Comment: In your code, you set the HotKey ID as `id = this.GetHashCode();` in your handler class. You should probably use a base ID, increment for each HotKey you add and store that ID in your Handler class. Instead, you overwrite a single handler object each time you create a new HotKey. -- In LParam, the HotKey ID is `int hotKeyID = m.WParam.ToInt32();`, the Key pressed is `var keyPressed = (Keys)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);` and the Modifiers `var modifier = (KeyModifier)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFF);`.

Comment: HotKeys are global, processed before the Keyborad input, so you actively remove the Key from the standard Input. Maybe you need [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) instead? -- BTW, you should really post your code here

Comment: I think you're consuming all the messages, so that no other app gets them

Comment: @EricSchneider you’re completely right. I just don’t know how to keep it from doing that

Comment: To get the keystrokes when your window is inactive you probably need to register a WH_KEYBOARD_LL this should not consume message

Comment: @Mateusz good idea. Im testing a bit with GetAsyncKeyState() but I will keep this in mind!

Comment: @Jimi This has been updated with the GetAsyncKeyState() method.

Comment: I tried to dig for it, but couldn't find info. Thought it might be a ",Handled = false;" thing but there seems to be no property or event for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

With the help of [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) and [this stack overflow form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325924/10082088), I was able to solve the problem I had.

By using the method [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) and a timer, I was able to constantly check if the keys `w, a, s, d` were being pressed down.

---

*Form1.cs*

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartTimer(timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W) <= -32767) label1.Text = Keys.W + " special";
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.A) <= -32767) label1.Text = Keys.A + " special";
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.S) <= -32767) label1.Text = Keys.S + " special";
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.D) <= -32767) label1.Text = Keys.D + " special";

            else label1.Text = "Nothing Pressed";
        }

        private void StartTimer(EventHandler eventHandler)
        {
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(eventHandler);
            timer1.Interval = 35;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Add this to *Form1.Designer.cs*

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
```

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState()` doesn't return a `bool`, it returns a `SHORT` (`short`). -- A `16ms` interval is too low for the WinForms Timer, don't set it below `35ms` (the *official* maximum resolution is `55ms`).

Comment: @Jimi I agree with the 35ms timer. The `GetAsyncKeyState()` however does return a bool if needed. I tested this with `if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W) == true) label1.Text = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W).ToString();` and it printed `True` on the screen. I believe there's a good reason to why you say to return a short so please let me know.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it returns a `SHORT` where the `MSB` and `LSB` has specific meaning. You shouldn't marshal a value for what it's not, it may get funky, usually with bad timing :)

Comment: @Jimi updated my if statements to check if the key is `<= -32767` since that's the value it returns when pressed. I used the `<=` since for half a second the value goes to `-32768`

Comment: More or less. You can check whether the value returned by `GetAsyncKeyState()` has the `MSB` set (as in  `unchecked((short)0b1000_0000_0000_0001)` which is of course `-32767`). In the answer you linked, the `MSB` is shifted 15 positions to the right (`((keyState >> 15) & 0x0001) == 0x0001`) and compared to `1`, to see whether the `MSB` is set. See the Docs about it.